Adding image to the center of the cell, while using addImage method of exceljs library
I am using addImage() method of exceljs library to add image to the cell of an excel file which is exported from my angular application. I am able to add image to cell of the exported file using addImage() method , but the image is added at the top left corner of the cell. However i want to add image at the center of the cell. how can this be achieved?
worksheet.addImage(child_imgId,{ tl:{col:1,row:rowCount-1},
                                  ext:{width : 78, height : 59},
                                  editAs:'absolute' }); 

worksheet.getRow(rowCount).height=70;
worksheet.getColumn(2).width = 14;


var rowR = Number(rowCount-1+0.15);
worksheet.addImage(child_imgId,{
                    tl:{col:1.5,row:rowR} ,
                    ext:{width : 78, height : 59},
                    editAs:'absolute',
                   }); 
                }


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
